# Regex Match on any Number Except

Tags: regex

I have this regex that I am trying to match on any except the following number

`0|1|2|3|4|5|6`

`^(?!(0|1|2|3|4|5|6)).*`

I can get it to match on 7 or 8 or 9, but 10 doesn't work nor does anything after since they start with a number that I don't want to match on.

For example, if my number is 22, then it would match.
If my number is 2, then it wouldn't match.

Comment: `([0-6]\d+|[7-9]\d*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can update your regex adding a word boundary `\b` after the group to:

[`^(?!(0|1|2|3|4|5|6)\b).*`](https://regex101.com/r/mbrfH7/1)

You could also write this shorter replacing the or statements with a character range from 0-6 like:
[`^(?![0-6]\b).*`](https://regex101.com/r/mbrfH7/2)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the fastest regex method (127 steps when checking against every number from 0 to 30).

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/lq1h3E/3)

```
\d{2,}|[7-9]
```

- `\d{2,}` Matches any 2+ digit numbers.
- `[7-9]` You can also use `[^\D0-6]` if you want to use the exclusion range instead of the accepted range.

Alternatively, switching the conditions around to get `[7-9]|\d{2,}` would improve performance if you have a greater chance of single-digit numbers.

Comment: Well, for starters faster than yours :P https://regex101.com/r/lq1h3E/5, but I did say when checking against every number from 0 to 30

Comment: It's not that 3 numbers match pattern 7-9, doesn't matter. An alternation is a simple jump. All single digits  have to take that jump to get to 7-9 anyway if trailing. And, how do you know if any sample of his are 2 or more digits. Statistically, who cares if there is infinity of numbers.

Comment: Also, it's a trivial overhead to confine it to accept only digits, instead of the free form of yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164110/discussion-between-ctwheels-and-sln).

Comment: @sln I've moved this to chat. Would you mind helping me clean up the rest?

Comment: I've removed the rat's ass comment, and added 1 final chat comment. There is nothing to clean up. Also, see @TommasoBelluzzo answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about `[^0123456]|(\d{2,})`? That way you can negate the ones you don't want, but it'll still match numbers with 2 or more digits.

Comment: That'll match `%` or any other character that isn't in `0123456`

Comment: he didn't mention the existance of non-number characters: "match on any except the following number"

Answer (score 1):

Try this `^(?![0-6]$)\d+$`

Will not match a string containing only 0-6, all other number(s) are ok.

---

Using this `^(?!0*[0-6]$)\d+$` will match *numerically*, numbers greater than 6.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
^(?:[7-9]|\d{2,})$
```

Visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/hrkXlQ/2) to test the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: `\b[7-9]\b|\b[1-9]\d+\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EQG8uJ/2)

Comment: +1 I like the `\b[7-9\b` part, word boundaries are the fastest check an engine can do. There might be an issue  `[1-9]\d+` its not clear if the OP cares about the resolved _numeric_ value, like `001` might be ok.

Comment: @sln You maybe right, but I don't think that's a case. He said numbers and gave example 1 to 6 and 22. So...

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can match numbers except 39 **/^+(([0-24-9][0-8]?[0-9]*)|([3][0-8][0-9]*)|([3]))$/**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since your answer doesn't directly solve the questioners answer it might be nice to explain how the regex works so they can understand how to adapt it.